# WiX install condition fails during repair in systems with UAC

Tags: installation, wix, uac

I'm having a problem with install conditions in maintenance mode that only happens in systems with UAC.  I'm doing a registry search to set a couple of properties that are used in the install condition.  This works during the intial installation, but when I try to do a repair or modify the feature selection, the install condition fails, and I get the message for the failed install condition.

This is what my wix source looks like:

```
<Product Id="MyProduct" ... >
  <Package InstallPrivileges="elevated" ... />
  <Condition Message="This installtion requires product X or Y. 
                      Setup will now quit.">
    <![CDATA[(MYPROPERTY1 OR MYPROPERTY2)]]>
  </Condition>

  <Property Id="MYPROPERTY1">
    <RegistrySearch Id="MySearch1"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\Company\ProductX"
                    Name="Installed"
                    Type="raw"
                    Win64="no"/>
  </Property>
  <Property Id="MYPROPERTY2">
    <RegistrySearch Id="MySearch2"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\Company\ProductY"
                    Name="Installed"
                    Type="raw"
                    Win64="no"/>
  </Property>

  <!-- ... Features and components and stuff ... -->
</Product>
```

I'm assuming that UAC is preventing my registry searches from happening, but I thought setting InstallPrivileges to "elevated" would cause a UAC prompt during repair.  I never get a UAC prompt though, the repair just fails.  If I disable UAC, then the repair works as expected.  Am I missing something else here?

Edit:  I should point out that the failure only happens when I choose "Change" from ARP, and then choose Repair.  If I choose "Repair" from ARP directly it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log the repair to see what properties AppSearch is setting.  Also consider putting "or Installed" on your conditions so that the conditions only apply during the initial install.  Nothing more annoying the can't install Product B because Product A was uninstalled first.

Update:  The AppSearch in the good log and bad log are behaving the exactly the same.  The problem is you didn't put the @Secure attribute on your property elements so that aren't listed in the SecureCustomProperties property.    If you look in the log you'll find a line that says "ignoring disallowed property".  For more information read:

[Reasons why your setup may fail on Windows Vista](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/VistaMSI/index.htm)

Comment: Christopher, thanks for your suggestions.  I was able to get rid of the bug by adding "OR Installed" to the install condition, though I still wonder what is causing the different behavior when UAC is active.  I compared the logs of no-UAC vs UAC, and all properties are being set in both instances, however, when UAC is active LaunchConditions returns 3 with no explanation for the difference.  The logs shows the Property being used has the correct value, so the failure is a complete mystery.

Comment: Hunted down your address @deploymentengineering.com.  I'd greatly appreciate it if you let me know if you find anything.

Comment: I'll try to look at that tonight.